# Resource error Xamarin.Forms (unexpected element & Ambiguity)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Suddenly having an error in my AndroidManifest
**"APP.Android\obj\Debug\100\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml   19"**

Also (Resolved - messed up with DevExpress)
**Ambiguity between 'Resource.Layout' and 'Resource.Layout' "APP.Android\MainActivity.cs    25  Active"**

It is working before and I didn't changed anything here:

```
TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.CustomTabbar;
```

Already delete the bin and obj folder and clean/rebuild the solution, but the error still exist.

[Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyeZS.png)

[AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H39ws.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For the error (`unexpected element queries found in manifest`) in your
> `AndroidManifest.xml`.

From document [Query & Interact with Apps in Android 11 with Package Visibility](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-11-package-visibility/), we could find that the `queries` element is a feature of Android 11, so you can try to update your nuget to the latest version and change your project `Target Framework` to Android 11 and try again.